# How I can keep Bootstrap cards the same size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with box sizing that includes general information. Depending if a particular card has an image, then card is bigger or smaller. How I can keep the box always with the same size?

```
<div className='card' syle='max-height:300px'>
  <img onError="this.src= 'https://d27jswm5an3efw.cloudfront.net/app/uploads/2019/07/insert-image-html.jpg'" className="card-img top max-height:50px" src={item.img !== undefined ? item.img : "https://d27jswm5an3efw.cloudfront.net/app/uploads/2019/07/insert-image-html.jpg"}/>
    <div className="card-body" syle='max-height:300px'>
      <h3 className="card-title">{item.subject}</h3>
      <p className="card-text">{item.description}</p>
      <div className="col-8-center">
      <div className="row justify-content-center">
      <div className='col-3 text-center'>Likes: <strong>{item.likes}</strong></div>
    </div>
      <button type='button' className='col-4 border bg-danger justify-content-center text-white btn-lg'>Dislike</button>
      <button type='button'className='col-4 border bg-success text-center text-white'>Like</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how it's displayed now:

Entries without a picture:
[image: Normal height, card does not have additional spaces]

Entry with a picture:
[image: Pictures with img]

Comment: youre using max-height which will never pushout to be 300px if there is no content inside  or the content is not 300 px, i suggest you use height for class='card'

Comment: syle='max-height:300px' instead of max-height use height and it's style not syle so also correct it

Comment: If you are using bootstrap > v4 then you need to just apply class h-100 to card to set height of all cards to same. For more info refer to official documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/card/#card-groups